# angular2 - how to style based on template variables if positive or negative

Tags: angular

I have this snippet that creates a table in angular2:

```
 <tr  class="d-tbody-tr" *ngFor="let row of rows;let i=index">
    <td *ngFor="let col of cols;let j=index">
        <label>{{ data_hash[row][col]}}</label>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

How do I style that if positive number black else red font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want change only the color you can use simply [style.color]

```
 <label [style.color]="data_hash[row][col] < 0?'red':''">{{data_hash[row][col]}}</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr  class="d-tbody-tr" *ngFor="let row of rows;let i=index">
 <td *ngFor="let col of cols;let j=index">
    <label [ngClass]="{'black': data_hash[row][col] >= 0, 'red': data_hash[row][col] < 0 }" >{{ data_hash[row][col]}}</label>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Additionally, create two classes in your css/scss file that add the relevant styles based on the class. E.g.

```
.black {
color: black; }
```

The ngClass directive will add the relevant class to the label tag based on the provided condition. If the value of data_hash[row][col] is greater or to zero, your label will have the .black class. For any values less than zero, it will have the .red class.